# Lowering Largest Contentful Paint, Over A Full Second After FCP On Mobile

Tags: wordpress, seo, pagespeed, core-web-vitals, largest-contentful-paint

I've spent quite a bit of time on performance optimization for my site and I'm right there at the finish line for getting all the green good scores in search console for mobile usability and core web vitals.  The last outstanding thing is getting my LCP under 2.5 seconds for my blog posts.

I'm consistently getting 2.6-2.7 and I can't quite figure out why.  The LCP element is the `<h1>` tag on my blog posts and there are no above-the-fold images.

[Example URL With Higher LCP](https://tortoiseandharesoftware.com/blog/essential-design-considerations-for-a-wordpress-website/)

Let me say that I am using a Beaver Builder website and some marketing tags like GA, GTM, etc but I've spent a lot of time analyzing my script and style loads to create an optimal experience with preconnects and preloads of various resources.  I know it's a big ask to try to get a site like this down in load time.  I'm on Kinsta hosting with low TTFB, full-page caching and CDN.  I am also using the Perfmatters plugin to control various aspects of load times.

I've done everything I can think of to get the LCP down and it seems like the `<H1>` tag is visible almost immediately but then may be repainted later towards the end of the page load, but I can't figure out the cause of this.

Anyone out there feeling generous that could take a look?

[Page Speed Insights URL](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftortoiseandharesoftware.com%2Fblog%2Fessential-design-considerations-for-a-wordpress-website%2F)

Comment: With the TTFB of 2.7 sec, you can do nothing with the LCP. You have to optimize the code or upgrade the server to minimize the server response time.

Comment: The TTFB is about .5, the LCP is averaging 2.6-2.7

Comment: TTFB on mobile is 2.7

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6YvbFfj.png

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem accurate, I know the site is coming in and out of good status on mobile.  I don't think that would be happening if that was truly the case for TTFB.  When I have been testing it, it has been .5 sec and that's what it's showing as average here: https://speedvitals.com/ttfb-test?url=https://tortoiseandharesoftware.com/blog/essential-design-considerations-for-a-wordpress-website/

Point taken though, I will see if I can investigate that part

Answer (score 0):

as i can see Pagespeed is showing aggregated real user experience of your entire domain, not of this specific pages but for all pages on this domain.

[image]

DOM content load time for your page on mobile is around 3sec, that means your LCP has to be greater than this

[image]

You need to reduce your DOM content load time first. You need to prioritize your network calls such that redundant dependency needs to be minimized

And also for desktop page, you are lazy loading first fold image which is not considered as a good user experience and might be contributing to LCP for desktop version of your page, also impact negatively for your SEO

[image]